# How to make a DIV tag clickable with a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could you please help me? I would like to be able to click on "Create Road Network" but nothing happens. Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/fh49807n/4/

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project structure</title>    
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li><div class="sticky">Project</div>
      <ul>
        <!-- Sub category -->
        <li><div class="sticky">Road Network</div>
          <ul>
            <!-- Skill -->
            <li><div><a href="http://google.com">Create Road Network</a></div>
            <li><div>View Roads Networks</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><div class="sticky">Zone set</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>Create Zone Set</div>
            <li><div>View Zones Sets</div>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you are mean exactly? Can you explain what you are try to make clickable?

Comment: You should update your question to also include your css, as in the fiddle.

Comment: Your problem is something to do with css not the html code.. because it should work, but doesn't

(i deleted all your css files and it worked)

Comment: Removing `z-index: -1` on your list elements made the link clickable.

Comment: @MaikLowrey, Is there away to reduce the tree by reducing the space between `li` and putting for example `Create Road Network` and `View Roads Networks` at the same level to `Road Network`?

Comment: @aba2s Hi! It is a new question and needs more details to clarify what you exactly wants to archive. You can ping me if you had created the new question. It is okay for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not because of `a` in `div`, but `ul` position

Your `ul` position is `absolute` and your `li` z-index is `-1` which is under `ul` layer. That makes your `a` is not clickable

The fix could be removing `z-index: -1;` in `.tree li`

```
.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}
```

Full code

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font: normal normal 13px/1.4 Segoe, "Segoe UI", Calibri, Helmet, FreeSans, Sans-Serif;
}

.tree ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 15em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  position: relative;
  /*relative;*/
}

.tree:before,
.tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: lock;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
}

.tree li:before {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  width: 2em;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  top: 1.5em;
}

.tree>li:before {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.tree li div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 15em;
  min-width: 15em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #8F949A;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tree {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.tree:before {
  border-left: none;
}


/*
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}*/
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project structure</title>
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css"-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div>
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <div class="sticky">Project</div>
        <ul>
          <!-- Sub category -->
          <li>
            <div class="sticky">Road Network</div>
            <ul>
              <!-- Skill -->
              <li>
                <div><a href="http://google.com">Create Road Network</a></div>
                <li>
                  <div>View Roads Networks</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="sticky">Zone set</div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div>Create Zone Set</div>
                  <li>
                    <div>View Zones Sets</div>
              </ul>
              </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

z-index make this problem. If you will remove it will be clickable.

```css
.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: -1; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While looking on your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/fh49807n/4/) i tried removing every single one of your css lines until it worked.. at the end i found this

you have to remove `position: relative;` in your `.tree li` after doing so the link will work

here is how the `.tree li` should look

```css
.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  /* position: relative; */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

you can also just make the link a seperate class with diffrent position

**EDIT**:
By looking at other answers i saw that removing the `z-index: -1` is a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
<li>
  <a href="https://www.google.fr/">
    <div>Create Road Network</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

It's working on the half of the div

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a link in your object..

But `cursor: pointer;` in your div class in css so it looks clickable.

Then go to your html file and put `onlick="window.location = 'YourLink'"` into your html tag.

For example:

```
<li onlick="window.location = 'https://google.com'">Test - Button</li>
```